# How to send a message to an actor's parent in Akka Classic?

Tags: java, akka

What is the method for an actor to send a message to its parent?

I'm using Akka 2.2

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are looking for

```
getContext().parent()
```

which gives you the ActorRef of the parent, so you can do

```
getContext().parent().tell(...)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be getContext().parent() and getContext().parent().tell(...)? Isn't parent a function?

Comment: `tell(...)` epects ActorRef - isn't following construction strange? `getContext().parent().tell("message",getContext().parent())`

Comment: `context.parent` in more recent versions (or perhaps just in scala)

Answer (score 17):

With Akka 2.4, you have to do `context.parent` inside an actor to have its parent actor reference. After that, you can send it a message as before (`context.parent ! "hello"`).

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted, e.g. for anybody who comes to this question through a search, that Akka 2.6 introduces a typed API for interacting with and defining actors and that the docs starting in version 2.6 guide towards using the typed API.

In an actor defined using the typed API, the `ActorContext` no longer directly provides an `ActorRef` to the parent actor, so the answers above won't work.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175028/send-message-to-parent-actor-in-akka-typed) for a (Scala) solution in Akka Typed.  The analogous Java API would be:

```
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Adapter

ActorRef parent = Adapter.toClassic(getContext()).parent()
```

Note that this is an untyped `ActorRef`: you can send any message to the parent actor, but the parent actor is not under any obligation to accept the message you send.